# Trying to prove a property for the region of convergence of a Laplace transform

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, solution-verification, laplace-transform, signal-processing

I've been studying Schaum's outlines for Signals and Systems, and came across this:

---

[image: image in question]

---

And I understood the part until $$ \int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}} |x(t)|e^{-\sigma_{0}}e^{-(\sigma_{1}-\sigma_{0})t}\,dt $$

Where did the $$ -\sigma_{0} -(\sigma_{1} - \sigma_{0})t $$ come from? Did the book add/divide the process? It didn't really explain what to do before that, so I might have overlooked something.

I got that the exponential with complex values is equal to one because of the absolute value, but after that, I get a bit lost by the addition of another exponential

Comment: I'm not sure that's exactly your question, but they just wrote $\sigma_1 t =(\sigma_1 -\sigma_0 +\sigma_0) t$ and then used the properties of the exponential

Comment: What's the notion or purpose of equating $ \sigma_{1}t $ to $ ( \sigma_{1} - \sigma_{0} + \sigma_{0})t $ though? I don't really know how it links up to proving that the ROC of X(s) becomes the entire s-plane after that